# What would happen if we had a device that produced oxygen inside of our lungs?

Tags: human-biology, breathing, human-physiology

Hypothetically speaking, suppose there is a device that produces a limitless supply of oxygen. The device is inhaled by a human and is resting inside the (a) lung.

What would hypothetically happen if this were possible?

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance on how/what to ask please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: We'd probably choke…

Comment: Depending on the efficiency/production of the hypothetical device, it might be [toxic](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the situation in which you want information about the device? i.e. in an oxygen-deprived person/athlete/underwater/etc. Also, a little more information about the hypothetical device would be useful (does it maintain normal atmospheric oxygen conc., or produce excess?)

Answer (score 6):

You might need to narrow your parameters a bit.

Just things to consider:

- Our lungs are not hollow organs that can accommodate an oxygen producing machine. They are basically narrow tubes that get smaller and smaller until they end in a tiny balloon-like structure - about 700 million of them. Where would the machine go?
- 100% oxygen is toxic to the lungs, as it is to many other things as well.
- How would the oxygen diffuse to all the other areas of the lung that need oxygen? Diffusion is a complicated process in a structure like the lungs.
- from what would it produce oxygen? For example, would it extract it from water? How would the body deal with the loss of moisture from the air in out lungs? Where would the excess hydrogen go?
- Hydrogen is highly flammable around 29%. Would we become fire-breathing?
- How would the machine not hyperinflate and thus injure the lung?
- How would we get rid of CO<sub>2</sub>? We would still have to breathe in and out.
- Etc.